# VMware vSphere whole-host backup

Tags: backup, vmware-vsphere

Is there a way to backup (and restore) an entire vSphere host (datastores and VMs included) to a file on a drive without vCenter (in the case of a disaster)?

Having looked at the manual and documentation, I can't seem to locate such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried out the ghetto backup script?

http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760